# Autoload PHPExcel 1.0 in Symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

We added PHPExcel to composer by adding the following

**To `repositories`:**

```
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "PHPOffice/PHPExcel",
            "version": "1.9",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.9"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-0": {
                    "PHPExcel": "src/"
                }
            }
        }
```

**To `require`:**

```
    "PHPOffice/PHPExcel": "1.9.*"
```

In our code:

```
use PHPExcel\IOFactory;

    ...


    $file = $request->get('file');

    $inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($file);
```

The error we get is:

```
Attempted to load class "IOFactory" from namespace "PHPExcel".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

The namespace looks right (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.9/src/PhpSpreadsheet/IOFactory.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of the 1.9 branch is not recommended. It isn't completely converted yet to use namespaces, and is subject to significant code change. Nor is it backward compatible with the official 1.8 branch, and the changes are not yet documented, and also subject to further major changes as we modify the code to take advantage of the newer features of PHP.

The official release branch is still 1.8

Just because the 1.8 branch exists on github, doesn't mean that it's working code. I store it there so that it's available for shared development, and as a security (rather than keeping it all on my development laptop) in case I get run over by a bus tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used 1.9.  Glad to see that they are moving to namespaces.  That said, you might be better off sticking with 1.8 just for stability.

In any event, 1.9 relies on psr-4.  Try adding this to your composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "PHPExcel\\": "src/PhpSpreadsheet"
    }
}
```

Then rebuilding the composer generated autoload.php file.